# hallar parejas de numeros

Tags: java

Por favor, alguien puede darme pistas porque el sgte código no me encuentra las parejas de números de 2 cifras que dan el mismo producto si Java se invierten las cifras de dichos números? Solo arroja la primera pareja. Gracias por la posible ayuda.

```
public class Parejas {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int prod1, prod2, op1, op2, temp1, temp2, rev1=0, rev2=0;

 for (int i = 11; i <= 99; i++)
 {
     op1 = i;
     temp1 = i;
     while(temp1 > 0)
     {
      rev1 = rev1 * 10;
      rev1 = rev1 + temp1%10;
      temp1 = temp1/10;
     }
     for (int j = 99 ; j >= 11; j--)
     {
         op2 = j;
         temp2 = j;
         while(temp2 > 0)
         {
          rev2 = rev2 * 10;
          rev2 = rev2 + temp2%10;
          temp2 = temp2/10;
         }

         prod1 = i * j;
         prod2 = rev1 * rev2;
         if (prod1 == prod2)
             System.out.println("Pareja hallada: " +i+ " y " +j);
             //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pareja hallada: " +op1+ " y " +op2);
     }
 }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene un pequeño problema de lógica:

Así el programa te muestre "todos" los posibles valores que invirtiéndolos dan el mismo producto, en realidad con tu código tal cual como esta, solo te mostraría 9 y los 9 son correctos, estos solo te los mostraria si al final o al inicio del primer for reseteas el valor de las variables rev1 y rev2 a 0, (ya que como nunca las reseteas en ninguna parte estas haciendo operaciones con valores antiguos que ya tenían estas al haber pasado por los diferentes ciclos), el resultado entonces por supuesto será que casi no habrán valores que coincidan:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int prod1, prod2, op1, op2, temp1, temp2, rev1=0, rev2=0;

         for (int i = 11; i <= 99; i++)
         {
             op1 = i;
             temp1 = i;

             while(temp1 > 0)
             {
              rev1 = rev1 * 10;
              rev1 = rev1 + temp1%10;
              temp1 = temp1/10;
             }

             for (int j = 99 ; j >= 11; j--)
             {
                 op2 = j;
                 temp2 = j;

                 while(temp2 > 0)
                 {
                  rev2 = rev2 * 10;
                  rev2 = rev2 + temp2%10;
                  temp2 = temp2/10;
                 }

                 prod1 = i * j;
                 prod2 = rev1 * rev2;
                 if (prod1 == prod2){
                     System.out.println("Pareja hallada: " +i+ " y " +j);
                     //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pareja hallada: " +op1+ " y " +op2);
                 }

             }

             rev1 = 0;
             rev2 = 0;
         }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, si de verdad deseas obtener todos los posibles parejas de valores que al multiplicarlas por su inverso dan el mismo resultado, entonces lamento decirte que con la lógica de tu código no es posible, o deberás hacerle varias modificaciones a tu código para que te lo permita, por lo pronto he creado el siguiente código para que contemple y te muestre todas las posibilidades:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        for(int i = 10; i <= 99; i++){

            String temp1 = Integer.toString(i);
            temp1 = Character.toString(temp1.charAt(1)) + Character.toString(temp1.charAt(0));
            int op1 = Integer.parseInt(temp1);


            for(int j = 99; j >= 10; j--){

                String temp2 = Integer.toString(j);
                temp2 = Character.toString(temp2.charAt(1)) + Character.toString(temp2.charAt(0));
                int op2 = Integer.parseInt(temp2);

                if((i * j) == (op1 * op2)){

                    System.out.println("Pareja hallada: " +i+ " y " +j);

                }



            }

        }

    }
}
```

Lo que hace el código es lo siguiente:

Al iniciar el primer for, se crea una variable llamada temp1 de tipo String (Es muy importante que sea tipo string, ya que de esta manera es como vamos a invertir nuestro numero), en este caso invertiremos el primer numero que equivale a i.

Como i es un entero, para que pueda ser guardado en temp1 como cadena de texto entonces hacemos la respectiva conversión a string:

```
String temp1 = Integer.toString(i);
```

Posteriormente intercambiaremos las posiciones de nuestra cadena de texto haciendo uso de la función charAt (Intercambiamos la pocisión 0 con la 1 y la 1 con la 0), (Esta recibe como parámetro un entero), y es la pocision del carácter que deseamos extraer, OJO esta función devuelve un dato de tipo **char**, el cual no es compatible directamente con un dato de tipo string, por lo que al hacer el intercambio, también debemos transformar ese dato de tipo char a string y concatenar ambas cadenas para así formar un nuevo string, este será el mismo numero pero invertido:

```
temp1 = Character.toString(temp1.charAt(1)) + Character.toString(temp1.charAt(0));
```

Ahora que tenemos nuestra cadena de texto que almacena el mismo numero pero invertido, simplemente almacenaremos este nuevo numero en la variable op1, ya que esta es de tipo entero, para ello debemos primero convertir esta cadena de texto a un entero para que pueda ser almacenada por la variable op1:

```
int op1 = Integer.parseInt(temp1);
```

Luego, al entrar en el segundo ciclo for, hacemos exactamente lo mismo, pero con variables diferentes, (temp2, op2), y dentro de este ciclo, simplemente comprobamos que si el producto entre los números sin invertir (i y j) es igual al producto de los numeros invertidos (op1 y op2), entonces mostraremos el mensaje:

```
if((i * j) == (op1 * op2)){

    System.out.println("Pareja hallada: " +i+ " y " +j);

}
```

Comment: Excelente gracias, ya había pilado lo del rev1 y rev2 pero no podía siquiera haberme percatado de ese "pequeño" problema al invertir las cifras, tu código funciona en este caso sin problemas, ahora tratar;e de invertir desde procedimientos llamados en mis for a ver que sucede(ya que quiero extenderlo a números de varias cifras), gracias de nuevo por ayudarme a "ver"!!